# Can you sketch the step response of a transfer function like this using just pen and paper and a simple calculator?

Tags: control, transfer-function

I have a transfer function like this:

$$H(s)= \frac{1}{10s^3+25s^2+10s+1}$$

If you have a transfer function that is composed of simple elements like P, I, D and second-order lag elements, you can find the poles and zeros then draw the step response by superposing the individual step responses from the pole-zero-diagram.

Is there also a way to simplify a term like this of the third degree so that you can draw the step response without having to use a computer or simulation program, or do you have to use limit theorems? Is it possible to find the poles of this term by calculating by hand?

Comment: Just like there's a quadratic formula, there's also a cubic formula. You can find the poles easily that way. There's a quartic formula too, but there isn't one for quintics.

Comment: Even for a 2nd order you need to find the roots, so it's no different for this case, or for any other: roots, partial fraction expansion, sum of residues, poles, and exponentials to give the impulse response. Integrate for step (or pre-add 1/s before partial fraction expansion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple calculator: -

[image]

Calculator found [here](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/algebra/cubicequation.php)

And here's a little bit of a piece of paper with the appropriate reverse Laplace transforms: -

[image]

Extract can also be found [here](https://www.studocu.com/row/document/addis-ababa-university/electromechanical-engineering/new-laplace-transform-table/3789120) item 15.

Get sketching.

Answer (score 1):

There must be at least one real first order root.

Find a 1st order real root (approximately, by trial and error, because you're only sketching).

Hence, find the (approximate) remaining 2nd order term by comparing coefficients or by long division.

Then partial fractions etc...